# Tcl/Tk write in a specific line

Tags: tcl, text-files, data-manipulation

I want to write in a specific line in Textdocument but there´s a Problem with my code, i don´t know where the bug is.

```
set fp [open C:/Users/user/Desktop/tst/settings.txt w]
set count 0
while {[gets $fp line]!=-1} {
    incr count
    if {$count==28} {
            break
    }
}
puts $fp "TEST"
close $fp
```

The File only contains TEST. 
Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Describe 'Problem'. From the code, it looks like you end up with a file containing only `TEST` though, is that right?

Comment: @Jerry yes youre right. The File only contains TEST

Comment: Ok and if there is already something on the line (in this case line 28) do you want to replace what's there or add to that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 'w' as access argument, which truncates the file. So you will loose all data from file while opening. Read more about [open](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/open.htm) command

You can use 'r+' or 'a+'.

Also To write after a particular line you can move the pointer to the desired location.

```
set fp [open C:/Users/user/Desktop/tst/settings.txt r+]
set count 0

while {[gets $fp line]!=-1} {
    incr count
    if {$count==28} {
            break
    }
    set offset [tell $fp]
}
seek $fp $offset
puts $fp "TEST"
close $fp
```

To replace a complete line it would be easier to do in following way. Rewrite all the lines and write new data on the desired line.

```
set fp [open C:/Users/user/Desktop/tst/settings.txt r+]
set count 0
set data [read $fp]
seek $fp 0
foreach line [split $data \n] {
    incr count
    if {$count==28} {
        puts $fp "TEST"
    } else {
        puts $fp $line
    }
}
close $fp
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont want to append to the file. I wanna to write in a specific line.. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: nice, but it split the previous record into 2 lines. Sorry maybe its my fault. i wanna replace a hole line with another.

Comment: @ManInTheMiddle Update in answer

Comment: Don't use `a+` for updating in the middle; it sets an OS-level flag to force writes to always happen at the end. `r+` is for updating an existing file, but if you are changing the number of bytes in the line (or inserting a line) then you might as well rewrite the whole lot.

Answer (score 4):

With short text files (these days, short is up to hundreds of megabytes!) the easiest way is to read the whole file into memory, do the text surgery there, and then write the whole lot back out. For example:

```
set filename "C:/Users/user/Desktop/tst/settings.txt"

set fp [open $filename]
set lines [split [read $fp] "\n"]
close $fp

set lines [linsert $lines 28 "TEST"]
# Read a line with lindex, find a line with lsearch
# Replace a line with lset, replace a range of lines with lreplace

set fp [open $filename w]
puts $fp [join $lines "\n"]
close $fp
```

Doing it this way is enormously easier, and avoids a lot of complexities that can happen with updating a file in place; save those for gigabyte-sized files (which won't be called `settings.txt` in any sane world…)

Answer (score 1):

```
package require fileutil

set filename path/to/settings.txt

set count 0
set lines {}
::fileutil::foreachLine line $filename {
    incr count
    if {$count == 28} {
        break
    }
    append lines $line\n
}
append lines TEST\n
::fileutil::writeFile $filename $lines
```

This is a simple and clean way to do it. Read the lines up to the point where you want to write, and then write back those lines with your new content added.

Comment: Lewering actually i cant use any packages, i have to code it in the classical tcl style.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest it would be easier to spawn an external program that specializes in this:

```
exec sed -i {28s/.*/TEST/} path/to/settings.txt
```