# How to write between two lines of text in an existing tcl file?

Tags: file, tcl, file-handling

I want to write in between two lines in an existing tcl file. For eg , I want to write some text between line 41 and 42. The new text should be in line 42 and the old text in 42 should go to 43 and repeatedly till the last line moving down by 1.

I tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37806536, but the text gets replaced.

Current:

```
set bCheckIPs 1
if { $bCheckIPs == 1 } {
   set list_check_ips "\ 
ip:proc_sys_reset:5.0\
ip:processing_system7:5.5\
ip:xlconstant:1.1\
ip:axi_dma:7.1\
ip:axis_data_fifo:2.0\
hls:trace_cntrl_32:1.4\
"
```

My expected output:

```
set bCheckIPs 1
if { $bCheckIPs == 1 } {
   set list_check_ips "\ 
ip:proc_sys_reset:5.0\
ip:processing_system7:5.5\
ip:xlconstant:1.1\
ip:axi_dma:7.1\
ip:sample:1.0\
ip:axis_data_fifo:2.0\
hls:trace_cntrl_32:1.4\
"
```

I want to add ip:sample:1.0\ inbetween ip:axi_dma:7.1\ and ip:axis_data_fifo:2.0\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwser was near, [just the next](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37812995).

Using that code, you could get a proc like this:

```
proc addtxtline {filename lineadd textadd} {
    # where filename: the file
    # lineadd: number of line to add - starting in zero
    # textadd: text to add
    set fp [open $filename]
    set lines [split [read $fp] "\n"]
    close $fp

    set lines [linsert $lines $lineadd $textadd]
    # Read a line with lindex, find a line with lsearch
    # Replace a line with lset, replace a range of lines with lreplace

    set fp [open $filename w]
    puts $fp [join $lines "\n"]
    close $fp 
}
```

Guessing you file was i.e, "settings.txt", you would call the function in this way:

```
addtxtline settings.txt 7  "ip:sample:1.0\\"
```

Saludos,

---

*Credit: [Donal Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301832/donal-fellows)*